# hCard: can it be used to semantically markup a business' contact details only?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup, microformats

Is it possible to markup a business' contact details using hCard? A name apparently is required in hCard: http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-authoring#The_Importance_of_Names (e.g. John Doe). I'm trying to mark up just a business' contact details. Is hCard useless to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An hCard has to have a name, but it doesn't have to be the name of a *person*; you can use hCard [for organizations](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-authoring#Organization_hCards) with markup like this:

```
<div class="vcard"><span class="fn org">Technorati</span></div>
```

Presumably the business whose contact details you're trying to mark up does have a name.

Comment: Yes, the business has a name. But there is a field for the business name, too. I guess in the absence of a person's name, then just promote the business name to the fn property. Hmmm ...

Comment: "Promote the business name to the fn property" isn't the best way to think about it. You're using two classes to say two different things about the business name. org says "this is an organization name." fn says "this is the name of the object this card represents." The two statements put together imply "this card represents an organization," but the meaning of the individual classes doesn't actually change between organization and person.

Answer (score 0):

Well, think of it. Why do you want to code it up as hCard? Because it allows other programs to automatically convert it to other formats or consume it otherwise. E.g., an hCard can be converted to a vCard instance in an address book.

Of what use would be an address book item without name? So, to come back, what use would have using hCard, when processing software can't gain something from it?

Comment: I'm trying to mark up a business' contact details, not a person.

Comment: Then I suggest to go with  Kurt Raschke's answer. Basically he re-states the paragraph directly below the one you linked in your question.